# Embedding private vimeo videos in tinymce

Tags: tinymce-4, vimeo-player

I'm having problems embedding private vimeo videos in tinymce. The videos are allowed to be embedded on the domain I'm using, and if I just add them outside of tinymce everything is ok.

Whenever added inside tinymce I'm faced with the "is not allowed to be embedded here" message from vimeo.

If I remove the privacy all together I can embed without any problems, so I assume the way vimeo detects the domain is the culprit, and probably the iframe inside iframe that the editor really is is to blame.

But that's how far I can follow. Anyone able to take it further?

Simple example is simply:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>
       tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <textarea>
      <iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/[video id]" width="500" height="375" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </textarea>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like TinyMCE creates an iframe around the contents without a src on the iframe, which means we don't see a domain and it fails the privacy check. I think your only option for getting it working in the preview is to make it public.